# Monitor ajax calls in Java

Tags: java, ajax, monitoring, newrelic, appdynamics

Can anyone suggest which Java application monitoring tools should we use for server side monitoring that can capture Ajax calls request.

Here we are trying to monitor an ERP application(Textiles Industries based "Now ERP"). In this, request are being sent are Ajax calls and those ajax calls are having same transaction/action name. For example :: "/now/HeaderRowProcess.abs" is business transaction which is being sent in each and every transaction made by the application. For reference Please refer "[1]: http://tinypic.com/r/15mbdqb/8".

This "Now" Application segregate there business transaction request on the basis of there "request parameters" rather than events or actions and also those request parameters are dynamic and depended upon the business transaction we are doing.

Could any one suggest any server side monitoring tool that will able to help us on this business transaction segregation basis of the parameter request rather than there events or actions.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Akshay Chouhan

Answer (score 0):

AppDynamics can handle this use case. We capture Ajax and also have the ability to handle single page apps.

Here are the docs for these two features:
https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO40/Configure+Virtual+Page+Naming+-+Beta
https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO14S/The+Ajax+Dashboard